# Remote access to glassfish server

Tags: java, web-applications, glassfish, remote-access

I am building an enterprise application with java and it is run in my local server such as localhost:8080/application. However if I want any friend to visit my web application through a different network and considering that I am just using a simple home network what steps can I take to make my application visible or accessible through an IP address? 
if it is not possible could it be accessible within the local network? 
I am asking this because my router can be access remotely through an IP address if it is turned on, and knowing my mac address maybe other devices from other networks might have the information to request the server to show my application.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this answer on ***askubuntu forums***. Here are the links for that

- [Creating a Web Page in Ubuntu and accessing it through Ethernet from another Ubuntu user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409136/creating-a-web-page-in-ubuntu-and-accessing-it-through-ethernet-from-another-ubu)
- [Installing Glassfish 4.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/glassfish/installing-glassfish-41-on-ubuntu)

When you go through the thread you will find **installing tomcat 7 on ubuntu and remotely accessing it within your network**.Hope you'll be able to apply it for **Glassfish server** on your server.

You'll also need virtual hosting.

- [Virtual Hostings](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=httpd&f=6)

Also this is a complete reference to access glsssfish remotely

- [Working remotely on Glassfish server](https://app.assembla.com/wiki/show/tudas/Working_remotely_on_Glassfish_server)

Hope these links provided here will help you!